# How to style cursor to prevent it from changing into classic middle click scroll cursor?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, cursor, vuetify.js

When you want to scroll just by mouse forward and backward(not by wheel), you use middle-click, cursor changes and you scroll easily on the web page.

Though I use `style="cursor: pointer"` and `@click.middle="middClickEvent()"` on vue elements, middle click with mouse runs my `middleClickEvent` but cursor turns from pointer to the scrolling like the above case for Chrome(I don't know what happens on other browsers).

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Have you tried calling `@click.middle="middClickEvent(event)"` and inside the `middClickEvent` function call `event.preventDefault();` ? :)

Comment: I don't think there is  a way to overwrite it, you may try to globally set !important to the cursor style but i think its more a browser overlay for that middle click style.

Comment: Tried using @click.middle.prevent but didnt work. Havent tried event parameter but I dont think it will have an effect. It is quite strange as a default browswer and I dont see it happen to me on many websites.

Answer (score 0):

add @mousedown.middle.prevent.stop and it will work